# Rails has_many through helper methods using non-primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

A `Firm` class declares `has_many :clients`, will add:

```
Firm#client_ids
Firm#client_ids=
```

Is there a way to change the association such that the following helpers are generated using non-primary keys from the clients table.

```
Firm#client_uuids
Firm#client_uuids=
```

My join table uses UUIDs and the has_many through relationships declare the correct primary and foreign keys. However these helper methods don't get updated.

Comment: I don't know, but is using the primary_key accessor an option? I don't think it will change those methods though. Perhaps it's an idea to alias those methods in your Firm model?

Also see: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The naming there is because it's the `.id` of the clients. You could alias the method if you really cared about that naming.

IMHO it's usually gross to use name attributes `_uuid`; the fact that it's a UUID/GUID/Integer/etc. should not be reflected in the naming + is an implementation detail. I'm still kicking myself on schemas that I've done that and then needed to change the primary key strategy.